# What's the differerence between PropertyInfo(s) retrieved from different scenarios

Tags: linq, expression

I have the following types:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId>
{
   public TId Id { get; set; }
}

public class Country : Entity<int>
{}
public class Language: Entity<int>
{}
```

And I have the following linq expression method:

```
internal static class ExpressionHelper
{
   public static PropertyInfo HasKey<TEntityType, TKey>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TKey>> keyDefinitionExpression)
   {
      LambdaExpression lambda = keyDefinitionExpression;
      MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
      return member.Member as PropertyInfo;
   }
}
```

1. 

I call 'GetProperty' to retrieve the property info:

```
PropertyInfo idCountry = typeof(Country).GetProperty("Id");
PropertyInfo idLanguage = typeof(Language).GetProperty("Id");
```

Where:  idCountry != idLanguage

It makes sense. But why are they different?

2)

```
PropertyInfo countryIdProperty = ExpressionHelper.HasKey<Country, int>(c => c.Id);
PropertyInfo languageIdProperty = ExpressionHelper.HasKey<Language, int>(c => c.Id);
```

Where:  countryIdProperty == languageIdProperty. ==> Why are they the same (equal)?

And   idCountry != countryIdProperty.  ==> Why are they different?

---

**Updates:**

```
public static PropertyInfo HasKey<TEntityType, TKey>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TKey>> keyDefinitionExpression)
 {
     LambdaExpression lambda = keyDefinitionExpression;
     MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
    
    Type callingType = typeof(TEntityType);
    PropertyInfo pInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (pInfo.ReflectedType != callingType)
    {
       return callingType.GetProperty(pInfo.Name);
    }
    
    return pInfo;
}
```

Is it the safe way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you acquired the first two values using reflection off of the `Country` and `Language` types, you got instances whose [`ReflectedType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype?view=net-6.0)s are tied to those classes.

The second two values were obtained by looking at a compiled expression tree. If you were to write code that accesses the `Id` property of one of these classes, you'd see that it compiles to a virtual call to the property on the `Entity<int>` class.

```
int Foo(Country c) => c.Id;
// Compiles to
IL_0000 ldarg.1 
IL_0001 callvirt    Entity <Int32>.get_Id ()
IL_0006 ret
```

There's nothing about the property access itself to indicate it's being performed on a different class, so the `ReflectedType` on the property in the expression tree is `Entity<Int32>`, rather than `Country` or `Language`.

If you want a more reliable way to determine whether two properties refer to the same effective property, you can combine the [`MetadataToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.metadatatoken?view=net-6.0) and `Module` properties.

```
Console.WriteLine((idCountry.MetadataToken, idCountry.Module) == (idLanguage.MetadataToken, idLanguage.Module)); // True
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's really helpful. By the way, do you know how can I get the same property info when I both use 'GetProperty' and 'ExpressionHelper.HasKey<Country, int>(c => c.Id)'?
I updated the original question, is the updates the safe way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I imagine that should work. But I would be curious about why it matters. For most use cases I can think of, it seems like other approaches might be more appropriate (for example, using a custom equality comparer).